# is it good to create static map in Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, static, hashmap

in my spring application i need to add a static map. in this map i can also add values at run time. so that i created a class called "DataSourcecContainerClass" and added list.

in my DataSourcecContainerClass:-

```
public class DataSourcecContainerClass {

public static Map<String,DataSource> dataSource=new HashMap<String,DataSource>();

}
```

it's working fine, but is this affect performance, and is it a good practice or not.

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend to use it ? As in if just like an utility it might be ok only if the values in `Map` does not contain any bean references.

Comment: the values never contain any bean references

Comment: Then I see no harm in using it as-is i.e. as long as `DataSourcecContainerClass` itself is not marked as spring bean

Comment: Also on side note there is no need for salutations, thanks, regards etc in post (*I have rolled back your edit which did the same*)

Comment: OK good please explain it as answer and also up vote my question bond

Comment: Where's the list?